# two divs side by side and nowrap, but the right one breaking down when not enough space

Tags: html, css

i can't get what i want, although it seems simple.

```
    <div class="around">
        <div class="first">
            <p>Some words</p>
        </div>
        <div class="second">
            <p>other words</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i have two divs side by side and each div has dynamic content.

[two divs side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtDKF.png)

and when browserwidth is getting to small for the content, the right div should break down.Important is, that the content in the right div align-righted is.
[two divs have no space, but not breaking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbH6Y.png)

i have read the other threads, but found nothing. and it think this is not possible, because i tried flex, grid, float, etc.... but maybe one of you has an idea

---

The solution:

```
    <style>
    .around {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .second {
        background: red;
    }
    .first,
    .second {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        min-width:0;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
<style>
.around,
.first,
.second {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
.first,
.second {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `display:flex` on the parent, and set the `flex` property to 1 in each of the children, allowing them to each take up the same amount of space from the parent.

the `min-width:0;` is a hack that helps in these situations, idk why.

```css
.around {
  display:flex;
  /* if you need the items to go to the next line if they are too big */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.first,.second {
  flex:1;
  min-width:0;
}

/* for demostration styling */
.around {
border:green 2px solid;
}
.first {
background:red;
}
.second {
background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="around">
    <div class="first">
        <p>Some words</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="second">
        <p>other words</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="around" style="width:100px">
    <div class="first">
        <p>Some words</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="second">
        <p>other words</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is already nice, but the content isnt breaking down, when not enough space.

Comment: @AlexanderWePunkt , I added a flex-wrap in case the items can be too big.

Answer (score 0):

Using `flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` I got it to do what you were trying to achieve.
You can make the divs of any size and once the screen width is too small for both divs to be on the same line, it will break up and have the red container move down.

```css
.around {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.second {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="around">
    <div class="first">
        <p>Some words</p>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <p>other words</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: doesnt work for me like wished. u have lost the "nowrap" - details

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure what you want. Do you want the children to wrap, or not? I understood from your original post that you want to wrap them. @AlexanderWePunkt

Comment: @AlexanderWePunkt you should accept the answer so that the community knows your issue is solved

Answer (score 0):

Divs by default go down when inserted , try "display:flex" property and give them spacing according to your requirement.

Comment: If you add the flex property, they will no longer go down and rather stay inline.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).